# Converting an ER diagram to SQL code

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, entity-relationship, create-table

[image]

This is the ER diagram, for which tables have to be made in SQL code implementing all the constraints. I made tables and tried implementing all the relationship via foreign keys, i jus wanted to confirm, whether these tables are correct or not.

1) Department table:

```
create table department(dpet_id number primary key, dept_name varchar2(15)
not null);
```

2) Branch table:

```
create table branch(branch_id varchar2(5) primary number, electives varchar2(10),
dept_id number references department(dept_id));
```

3) Course table:

```
create table course(course_id number primary key, course_name varchar2(10)
not null,branch_id varchar2(5) references branch(branch_id));
```

4) Student table:

```
create table student(stud_id number primary key, stud_name varchar2(30) not null,
branch_id varchar2(5) references branch(branch_id);
```

5) Applicant table:

```
create table applicant(app_id number primary key, stud_id number constraint fk
references student(stud_id) constraint stu_unq unique);
```

6) Applicant_branch table:

```
create table applicant_branch(app_id number references applicant(app_id),
branch_id varchar2(5) references branch(branch_id));
```

Do these tables conform to the ER diagram ?

Comment: @DanBracuk, Yes, I did this in Oracle 11g.

Comment: Please don't cross-post: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47707/converting-er-diagram-to-tables-and-relationships-in-sql

Comment: It's been a while since I created oracle tables, but your syntax looks wrong.  Have you tried to run these?  As an aside, why is your branch id varchar2 instead of a number?

Comment: @DanBracuk, Branch_id is declared varchar2() because it has to contain entries like B1, B2, B3 etc., Apart from this, Can u point out more mistakes , if any ?

Comment: The proper syntax for creating tables is available at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables003.htm.  For the branch, I suggest a numeric primary key and with a separate column for B1, etc.  Put a unique contstraint on it if required.  Finally, while your code more or less reflects what is in your diagram, your diagram might not satisfy real world requirements.  If a student can take more than one course from more than one branch, you need to give this more thought.

Comment: @DanBracuk The syntax is correct - except (3) minor mistakes; a typo in the 1st table (`dpet_id` vs `dept_id` in 1st table), a missing parenthesis in the 4th table and `primary number` vs. `primary key` in 2nd table.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is cross posted at http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47707/converting-er-diagram-to-tables-and-relationships-in-sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ER diagram depicts a conceptual model of the subject matter.  This is a good thing.

For future reference, there are two intermediate steps between an conceptual model and an SQL create script.  They are logical design and physical design.

Logical design changes the conceptual model into a logical model, and adds some features.  The logical model is relational (in most cases).  One added feature is foreign keys.  This is where you normalize, if you choose to normalize.

Physical design changes the logical model into a physical model, and adds some features.  The physical model is expressed in SQL terms; like tables, rows, and columns.  It is DBMS specific.  It adds features like indexes and many DBMS specific features such as tablespace mapping and others.  At this stage you consider the volume of data, the anticipated traffic, and throughput consideraions.

Finally, you convert the physical model into a create script.

For very small problems,  these stages can be collapsed into one stage, as you appear to have done.  For very big projects, it's better to keep them separate.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing i can add up to this is that there is no relationship between student and department. It depends on your scenario, you want it or not. But i think it should be. So that you can distinguish between the students of a prticular department.

Also you are making a picture like branch will come under department is this the case?

Comment: Yes, branch comes under department in this case. Is everything else fine ?

Comment: Ok. Rest of the things are fine.

Comment: Student determines Branch and Branch determines Department.   There is an indirect relationship.